# Can the default value of one column be another column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If no value is entered in the description column in the product table, I want it to be equal to that in the product_name column by default. I tried it as follows but it didn't work. Is this possible?

`CONSTRAINT def_desc DEFAULT product.product_name FOR description;`

Comment: Is this for Oracle or SQL Server? Please correct the tags...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common solution is to create a view for displaying the data. In the view you compute the description. Like this

```
CREATE TABLE t
(name VARCHAR2(10),
 description VARCHAR2(10));
 
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW t_v (name, description)
AS 
SELECT name, NVL(description, name) FROM t;

INSERT into t (name, description) VALUES ('CAR','cool car');
INSERT into t (name, description) VALUES ('BIKE',NULL);

SELECT * FROM t_v;

NAME       DESCRIPTIO
---------- ----------
CAR        cool car  
BIKE       BIKE
```

Comment: I've never heard of the NVL function. Really this could solve my problem. Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: happy to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 2):

No.  The default value can be a constant or (in general) a non-volatile function.  That is, a function value that doesn't change each time you call it.

Some databases such as SQL Server allow any function.

The logical issue with using another column is how to handle the value when the referenced column changes.  If you run:

```
create table t (
     x int,
     y int default x
);

insert into t (x) values (1);

update t set x = 2;
```

Then does `y` have a value of `1` or `2`?  If you want `y` to be `2`, then you can use a computed column.

Comment: I never thought this way :) I wanted to do this so that the column is not empty, but as you said, it can cause other problems. Thank you.

Comment: @uckocaman . . . I'm surprised you unaccepted this answer.

Comment: I'm sorry I gave the wrong answer. I was going to write on the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is to use only default, then no. If you want the column to be not empty, you can always have a constraint.

If the scenario you are facing doesn't allow you to make the field mandatory, then you can use a trigger. It updates just the way you want.

Comment: I didn't want to add constraints. I wanted the user to be able to enter a blank value, but to have a default value.

I did some research yesterday and thought it could be done with trigger as you said. I will try today, I hope I can :). Thank you.